# Herokuproblem pushing problem: error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/wwwwwww.git'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli, heroku-ci

I am trying to push my Rails app to Heroku but it is showing me this error again and again. What is the problem?

```
Enumerating objects: 140, done.
Counting objects: 100% (140/140), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (122/122), done.
Writing objects: 100% (140/140), 145.92 KiB | 1.50 MiB/s, done.
Total 140 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.21
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-20/ruby-2.7.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-20/ruby-2.7.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     You are trying to install ruby-2.7.0 on heroku-20.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Ruby ruby-2.7.0 is present on the following stacks:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     - heroku-18
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to first-rails-application11.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/first-rails-application11.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/first-rails-application11.git'
```

I ran `heroku login` and `heroku create`, and after completing some steps I ran `git push heroku main` and got this error. I also tried  `git push heroku main: main`, but that didn't change anything. Then I created a branch and then for example, `dev` then I ran `git push heroku dev:main` but its again failing.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with how you are pushing to `main`. Creating a branch and explicitly naming the remote branch when you push won't help.

Take a closer look at the error message:

```
remote:  !     The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     You are trying to install ruby-2.7.0 on heroku-20.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Ruby ruby-2.7.0 is present on the following stacks:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     - heroku-18
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
```

Ruby 2.7.0 is not supported, but if you visit [the page mentioned in the error message](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes) you should see that version 2.7.*3* is supported (at the time of writing).

[Update your `Gemfile` accordingly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions#selecting-a-version-of-ruby), commit, and redeploy.